# Default image when target is missing?

Tags: jquery, lightbox

My html has many automatic links to a PNG repository. When images don't exist (that happens sometimes) I would like lightbox to show a default image saying something like "Non available", instead of showing a blank image.

Can It be done? Thanks.

Comment: [jQuery/Javascript to replace broken images](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/92720/jquery-javascript-to-replace-broken-images)

Comment: The best answer (in my opinion) from Andreas' link: `$('img').one('error', function(){ $(this).attr('src', 'broken.jpg'); });`

Comment: configure the server to serve the error-image when a non-existing image has been requested

Comment: I found much more interesting to add a rewrite rule to appache2  to deal with all broken images. Thanks all.